# Simple Haskell Gloss program won't run on Windows 8 (Using LTS Haskell 16.27 with ghc-8.8.4)

Tags: haskell, glut, gloss

I have the following gloss program:

```
module Easy where

import Graphics.Gloss

main :: IO ()
main = display (InWindow "My Window" (200,200) (10,10)) white (Circle 80)
```

However when I run `stack runghc Easy` I get the following error:
`Easy: user error (unknown GLUT entry glutInit)`
I tried copying `freeglut/bin/(platform)/freeglut.dll` to `C:\Windows\System32` and renaming it to `glut32.dll` but the error remains. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

From [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskellquestions/comments/31kb85/having_trouble_getting_gloss_to_install_on_windows/):

> I got GLUT to install! I'd been using the 32-bit version of the DLL,
> but I switched to the 64-bit version and got it to build. For the
> record, I downloaded this:
> http://files.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/development/GLUT/freeglut-MinGW.zip
>
> I unzipped it to D:\Projects\libs, which is where I have my
> third-party libraries, so there's now a D:\Projects\libs\freeglut
> directory with include, lib, and bin subdirectories. The 64-bit DLL is
> in an x64 subdirectory in bin.
>
> Next, I made a copy of D:\Projects\libs\freeglut\bin\x64\freeglut.dll
> in the same directory, naming it glut32.dll.